# How is Mapquest Nominatim Service's "routeWidth" search param implemented?

Tags: open-source-gis, openstreetmap, reverse-geocoding

I was looking at MapQuest's Nominatim service, and it seems like they have a non-standard search parameter (doesn't seem to exist in standard Nominatim's list of params) that is the routeWidth. Any guess how this is implemented in their service?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**routewidth** > Specify the buffer radius of a route. Acceptable values are between 0 and 1 (in degrees).

Example:
http://open.mapquestapi.com/nominatim/#search_route

routeWidth is set here:

```
http://open.mapquestapi.com/nominatim/v1/search?json_callback=renderExampleAdvancedResults&format=json&bounded=1&q=[parking]&routewidth=0.5&route=38.888809,-77.637832,38.889148,-77.63227,38.889148,-77.63227,38.845741,-77.636726,38.845741,-77.636726,38.830371,-77.633094,38.830371,-77.633094,38.820507,-77.636291,38.820507,-77.636291,38.817859,-77.640121,38.817859,-77.640121,38.797801,-77.584991,38.802032,-77.511245,38.820514,-77.464691,38.845779,-77.434837,38.880325,-77.237571,38.897205,-77.199356,38.897205,-77.199356,38.897197,-77.19432,38.897197,-77.19432,38.894683,-77.190422
```

Comment: Thanks Mapperz, but my question is about how it is implemented in the library (and not how to use it). MapQuest seems to have retrofitted Nominatim with this notion of "routeWidth", and I'd like to know how they did it. Since I'm new to all this my question may not make sense or appear misguided. If that is the case, please point that out to me too.

Comment: if your run the route - it calculates the route - then uses the route as a line - this is buffered (creates a polygon) - the buffered polygon is then intersected with the points of interest db - then a list is generated.

Comment: .js is here http://open.mapquestapi.com/media/js/samples/nominatim/exampleAdvanced.js

Answer (score 0):

The parameter is part of the next release of Nominatim which you can find the source for here: http://svn.openstreetmap.org/applications/utils/nominatim/

The new version has not yet been released but will be in the next few weeks.